# Ошибка в скрипте с curl

Tags: php, curl

```
$postdata = array(
        'login' => $this->HD_login,
        'password' => $this->HD_password,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->HD_url . "/ptn/hd_auth");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookieHD.txt");
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
```

В $result пусто
curl_getinfo показывает

```
[url] => http://127.0.0.1:2266/ptn/hd_auth
[content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
[http_code] => 405
[header_size] => 247
[request_size] => 178
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.326581
[namelookup_time] => 3.4E-5
[connect_time] => 0.024598
[pretransfer_time] => 0.024682
[size_upload] => 45
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
```

В чем может быть косяк?

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed — указанный клиентом метод нельзя применить к текущему ресурсу

Comment: Проблема решена.
Форма авторизации была изменена и я не заметил, что нужно отправлять дополнительные данные в массиве $postdata